# two predicates in one sentence

Tags: sentence-structure

> **Next, previous work *shows*, the scout *recruits* a new scout to join her on a trek to the good site.** She dashes around tapping her antennae on other ants and releasing a pheromone from her sting gland, explains Stephen Pratt of Arizona State University in Tempe. Usually she finds a volunteer within a minute or so, and the two set off tandem running.

Please help me comprehend why two predicates, shows and recruits, were used in one sentence by the author in the bold sentence? I think a period should've been used here.

Answer (score 1):

It is a complex sentence with the main clause (***previous work shows***) and the dependent object clause (***the scout recruits a new scout to join her on a trek to the good site***). The main clause consists of the subject ***Previous work*** and predicate ***shows***. The object clause consists of the subject ***the scout*** and the predicate ***recruits*** (the rest of the sentence I won't explain because it doesn't play a vital role in your question).
If you put a period and leave a sentence just like this ***"Previous work shows"***, the sentence won't be complete and it doesn't make sense at all. So what does previous work show? There should be a continuation answering this question. It shows that the scout recruits a new scout to join her on a trek to the good site.

Comment: Thanks for you thorough explanations, but I still have doubt that since it is a object clause, shouldn't it better be written as "previous work shows that the scout recruits a new scout to join her on a trek to the good site." I mean, to use "that" instead of a comma?

Comment: "that" can be used here as well, but the meaning is the same. You are right that a comma in this sentence is a weird choice.  Usually, when a dependent clause comes after the independent clause, most of the time there is no comma.
Is the sentence taken from a newspaper article? Sometimes newspapers tend to make sentences more concise.

Comment: from a reading passage of ACT test. I don't quite remember, but these passages normally were adapted from newspaper outlets like NYT...